# Installing Packages via Y PPA Manager (newest version)

Tags: ppa

How install packages via the newest version of Y PPA manager?  I know they removed it, but I would like to know if there is a way still.

Comment: I've never seen an option to install packages via Y PPA. It's always been for managing PPA's not packages.

Comment: @ElderGeek they had an option to install packages from it, but it didn't work well and not many people used it, so they scrapped the feature in March.

Comment: @OP. I believe you can still download the packages, so why not do that and then install them by double clicking?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Interesting. Can you cite a source? I've been using Y PPA since 2012 and don't recall seeing that feature.

Comment: @Zacharee1Not what I want

Comment: @ElderGeek http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/y-ppa-manager-updated-with-important.html

Comment: Thank you for that information. It seems to answer your question, so why not write up the answer "No" with the link as a source? Just because an answer isn't the one you want doesn't mean it's wrong.